OIC GET Method for a REST API with filters
I am trying to invoke a UDSA exposed rest API from OIC (Rest Adapter to be specific).
https://mpr.datamart.ams.usda.gov/ws/report/v1/cattle/LM_CT100?filter={"filters":[{"fieldName
":"Report%20date","operatorType":"EQUAL","values":["01/10/2018"]}]}
The API itself has multiple filters (derived in JSON format) and work fine over the browser or on an API client like Postman.
However, I am unable to model the query in my OIC rest adapter trigger for the same.
I was trying to pass the filter condition it as a POST request body, but that is not permitted.
Any pointers?

This URL does not work filter
GET https://mpr.datamart.ams.usda.gov/services/v1.1/reports

This URL does work filter
GET https://mpr.datamart.ams.usda.gov/services/v1.1/reports/{report number}

Example
https://mpr.datamart.ams.usda.gov/services/v1.1/reports/2466?q=report_date=01/10/2018

{
  "reportSection": "Summary",
  "reportSections": [
    "Summary",
    "Detail",
    "History"
  ],
  "stats": {
    "totalRows:": 1,
    "returnedRows:": 1,
    "userAllowedRows:": 99999
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "report_date": "01/10/2018",
      "previous_day_head_count": "37,373",
      "same_day_prev_week_head_count": "550",
      "same_day_prev_year_head_count": "19",
      "current_week_head_count": "68,620",
      "previous_week_head_count": "550",
      "previous_year_head_count": "857",
      "is_correction": null,
      "narrative": null,
      "report_title": "5 Area Daily Weighted Average Direct Slaughter Cattle - Negotiated (PDF) (LM_CT100)",
      "slug_name": "AMS_2466",
      "slug_id": "2466",
      "office_name": "St Joseph, MO",
      "office_code": "LS-SJ",
      "office_city": "Saint Joseph",
      "office_state": "MO",
      "market_location_name": "St. Joseph, MO",
      "market_location_city": "St. Joseph",
      "market_location_state": "MO",
      "market_type": "Direct Livestock - LMR Cattle",
      "market_type_category": "Direct Livestock - LMR Cattle",
      "published_date": "01/10/2018 10:32:45"
    }
  ]
}


Detail documentation in here

In OIC, the right way would be to create to create a Rest API Invoke and pass the filter section as a variable to the actual URL.
Step1: Create a variable and assign it value of the Query Parameter.
VFilter = '{%22filters%22:[{%22fieldName%22:%22Report%20Date%22,%22operatorType%22:%22EQUAL%22,%22values%22:[%222023-06-05%22]}]}'

Step2: Map the variable to the QueryParameter filter

Step3: Pass the variable to the QueryParamter

Step4: Upon triggering the integration, filter string is passed as query Parameter.
<nstrgmpr:execute xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:ns22="http://xml.oracle.com/types/REST/Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data_REQUEST" xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data_REQUEST/types"><nstrgmpr:QueryParameters><ns22:filter>{%22filters%22:[{%22fieldName%22:%22Report%20Date%22,%22operatorType%22:%22EQUAL%22,%22values%22:[%222023-06-05%22]}]}</ns22:filter></nstrgmpr:QueryParameters></nstrgmpr:execute>

